# Can I reset my account password for our cloud domain via the Azure portal?

Tags: azure, active-directory, change-password

My domain account is locked out and I can't get access to any VM, including our domain controller. I still have full access to our portal. Is there any way that I can reset my domain account password via the Azure portal?

[image: RDP Dialog]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to unlock my account using the following powershell command

```
Unlock-ADAccount -Identity username
```

(Where 'username' is the user name of the AD account.)